# spring websocket send messages to specific users

Tags: spring-boot, spring-websocket

I am developing a Springboot application which has a websocket server to handle messages coming from different users. I need to develop this server such that a  socket client can send messages to specific client. Below given is my WebSocketHandler class.

```
public class WebSocketHandler extends AbstractWebSocketHandler {
static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(WebSocketHandler.class);

@Override
protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) throws Exception {

            String payLoad = message.getPayLoad();

            session.sendMessage("message : "+payLoad+" is received!!!");
            ////
        }
    }

}
```

}

I prefer to use a one handler instance as given below.

```
public class WebSocketConfiguration implements WebSocketConfigurer {
static WebSocketHandler handler = new WebSocketHandler();

@Override
public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry webSocketHandlerRegistry) {
    webSocketHandlerRegistry.addHandler(handler,"/websocket");
}
```

}

Is there way to achieve this ? Thanks everyone.